# how to make a configuration file in python Flask for Logging file

Tags: python, flask

**Hello guys i have a configuration file named as "LoggingConfig" containing all data** please Before dislike this code tell me what you need coze **i don't know how to implement the config and use in Flask program.**so please help **This is the config file  i have created:**

```
import logging
#  create and configure logger

    def logger():
        logger=logging.getLogger("DATA-MANUFACTURING") 
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # create console handler and set level to debug
        ch=logging.StreamHandler()

        # create formatter
        lOG_FORMAT= "%(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
        logging.basicConfig(filename="C:\\Users\\rahul\\Desktop\\DATA-MANUFACTURING.log", level = ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG), format = lOG_FORMAT, filemode = "a")
```

I want to import to my flask program for this i have written a prog like this:

```
import logging
import LoggingConfig
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import os
from random import randint
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, make_response
LoggingConfig.logger()

app = Flask(__name__)

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
..................................
..................................
so on.........
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

my program have lots of things which i have not given here the only thing i want to make a config file get access in my flask program please if you want me to write whole program here please txt me in text box will add that...thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different way of configure Logging Files:
Go This site for more info : https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/logging/
For You i prefer INI- format
Go to your program make one more file named as "Yourfilename.ini"

```
[loggers]
keys=root,DATA-MANUFACTURING

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=fileFormatter,consoleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_DATA-MANUFACTURING]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler
qualname=DATA-MANUFACTURING
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('logfile.log', 'a')

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Now in your main program write on the top:

```
import logging.config
logging.config.fileConfig( 'logging.ini') 
logger = logging.getLogger('DATA-MANUFACTURING')
.........................................
```

and write any logging info whatever you want

```
logger.info("Loading the UpoadFile page")...so on.
```